# invalid object on a table that exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting an "invalid object" warning error in the Management Studio query. Any query against the table works and it links correctly to another table. I am investigating an error that I'm getting in C#. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409788/is-not-a-foreign-key-column-and-cannot-be-used-here
This is the latest attempt to ferret out what may be going wrong. My linq queries against this table fail, but when I go to classic ADO.NET using SQL strings they work perfectly. Is it possible that this "invalid object" is causing C#/linq to kill the connection?
How do I get the table to stop the "invalid object" error. There are two tables, the following is the simplest one:

```
USE [Report]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHoliDate](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Holiday] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DOW] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

It is nothing more than a table of holidays used to calculate the business days between two dates.

**edit**
Any reference to the table will do (which is why I didn't add a query).

```
SELECT * FROM tblHoliDate
```

Mouse over the table name to see the error.
The exact error is "invalid object name tblHolidate". This only occurs on mouse-over and the results of any SQL query against the table are complete and correct.

Comment: You might want to show the code that generates the error, and the exact text of the error.

Comment: My guess?  You're in the context of the wrong database.  Regardless, run a SQL Trace or XE session and see what exactly is happening on the database.  Then you'll have your answer.

Comment: I wish it was that easy. Good suggestion.

Comment: Without seeing the exact error text, I can only think of a few things it could be:  1) the object actually doesn't exist 2) wrong database 3) the current principle doesn't have permissions on the object.

Comment: Sounds like you're pointing to Active Directory. Could Be! Checking with Sys Admin.

Comment: The warning on mouse over should be from the auto complete feature, it's my guess. Try refreshing the cache for Intellisense in Management Studio.

Comment: Glad I could help, copying the comment in the answer. Please see the question from the SO question and let me know. thanks.

Comment: I thought your problem was also with a query...?

Comment: @ThomasStringer: they're pretty unrelated, as I guess. OP just wanted to verify a hunch (where warning of non existing table might be somehow related to an error he gets using LINQ, but not in normal SQL or ADO).

Comment: @Marian Oh absolutely, I couldn't agree more.  A classic case of IntelliSense not refreshing wouldn't cause that error when running a query.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen that error in more than 10 years of SQL programming. Yes, I grasping at straws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning on mouse over should be from the auto complete feature, it's my guess. I've met that a few times. Especially with newly created tables in a session.
Try refreshing the cache for Intellisense in Management Studio and this should fix it.

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not fix my original problem which has to do with accessing this table using linq. :(

Comment: These are unrelated issues, I'm afraid. This one is a Management Studio warning, that one is an application error.

Comment: I had the same problem with linq accessing the database, turned out my connection string was pointing to the wrong database